the role of supp(f) in the change of variables formula
I learned that the change of variables formula,but I can't understand why we require that supp(f) is contained in φ(U).What will happen if I remove this condition？

Theorem — Let U be an open set in Rn and φ : U → Rn an injective
differentiable function with continuous partial derivatives, the
Jacobian of which is nonzero for every x in U. Then for any
real-valued, compactly supported, continuous function f, with support
contained in φ(U):


Well, if we are assuming that $f$ is compactly supported, we may as well assume that our domain of integration contains the entire support of $f$. Otherwise, we would choose our domain of integration differently.
